# Alert before switch to maps if clicking on address in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, maps

I am using the following code to detect if a link is clicked in a UIWebView and show an alert. So the user needs to confirm to leave the app. The detection for addresses in also active. If the user is tapping on an address you directly switch to the Maps app from Apple. I want to detect this as well to show an alert before switching to the Maps app. How can I detect if an address(location) is clicked in an UIWebView?

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    savedLink = [request URL];
    if ( ( [ [ savedLink scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http" ] || [ [ savedLink scheme ] isEqualToString: @"https" ]) && ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) ) {
        UIAlertView *leaveApp = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"You want to leave the app?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [leaveApp show];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:savedLink];
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"No"])
    {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reported `scheme` of the `[request URL]` when you click on the location?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please explain?

Comment: You are checking for `[savedLink scheme]` matching `@"http"` and `@"https"`. Presumably you could just add another one in there if it matches whatever a location's `scheme` returns to you.

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting something like maps.apple.com but the scheme is called x-apple-data-detectors.
If I am looking for that scheme it is working.

```
[[savedLink scheme] isEqualToString:@"x-apple-data-detectors"]
```